# Ansible mount module update fstab that fails status check in EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, fstab

Here is my Ansible Task -

That mount a directory with an external ebs volume in EC2 instance to make an [Amazon EBS volume available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html).

```
- name: Create Data directory #1 
  file:
    path: "{{ data_directory }}/"
    state: directory
  
- name: Get the EBS volume/block #2
  shell: lsblk -x SIZE | grep disk | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
  register: ebs_nvme_block
  check_mode: false

- name: Printout the block #3
  debug: 
    var: ebs_nvme_block.stdout_lines[0]

- name: Create a xfs filesystem on EBS volume #4
  filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: "/dev/{{ ebs_nvme_block.stdout_lines[0] }}"
  ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"

- name: Get UUID of ebs volume #5
  shell: lsblk -o +UUID | grep "{{ ebs_nvme_block.stdout_lines[0] }}" |  awk '{print $NF}'
  register: uuid
  check_mode: false

- name: Print UUID #6
  debug:
    var: uuid.stdout

- name: Mount the ebs volume with /data directory #6
  mount:
    backup: yes
    path:  "{{ data_directory }}" 
    src: "/dev/{{ ebs_nvme_block.stdout_lines[0] }}" # or use UUID={{ uuid.stdout }}
    state: mounted
    opts: defaults,nofail
    dump: 0
    passno: 2
    fstype: xfs
  ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"
```

Now this #6 code block mounts and creates a backup of `/etc/fstab` and updates as follows

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/nvme1n1 /data xfs defaults,nofail 0 2
```

If I use `UUID` to mount then the `/etc/fstab` is modified as

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /data xfs defaults,nofail 0 0
```

#7 block code update the `/etc/fstab` as

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
UUID={{ uuid.stdout }}  {{ data_directory }}  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2
```

Everything works fine. I don't receive any error while mounting but whatever the reason the EC2 instance is getting **Status check** error [`1/2 checks passed`].

1. 1st question is - is there any format of `/etc/fstab` file. is there single space or double space in between values?
2. From here [How fstab works](https://geek-university.com/linux/etc-fstab-file/) and [Make an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html), what I got is

- there are 2 spaces in between fields. When Ansible modifies the `fstab` file, it doesn't create any extra space.

`UUID=aebf131c-6957-451e-8d34-ec978d9581ae  /data  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2`

`UUID=aebf131c-6957-451e-8d34-ec978d9581ae /data xfs defaults,nofail 0 2` [Ansible modifies]

- **Does it have any effect in status check?**

2. Ansible creates the backfile as `fstab.DATETIME~` . Same question, does this backup file has any effect of status check error.

Comment: The number of blank lines in fstab and the number of spaces between fields are both irrelevant. The backup file has no effect either.

Comment: Which status check is failing? The instance reachability check or the system status check? And are you logged in to the instance OK whilst it's displaying the failed status check?

I kind of doubt that mounting the EBS volume has anything to do with the reason the EC2 status checks are failing.

Comment: I think it is instance reachability check.